# When to use Spring Web Flow?

Tags: spring, flash, spring-webflow

I'm interested by this framework (spring web flow) and I want to know when it's best to use spring flow and if it can help , when it comes really handy ?

and also , is there any other solutions ?

Regards

Comment: [Spring Web Flow is a Spring MVC extension that allows implementing the "flows" of a web application. A flow encapsulates a sequence of steps that guide a user through the execution of some business task. It spans multiple HTTP requests, has state, deals with transactional data, is reusable, and may be dynamic and long-running in nature.](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow) (first paragraph of Springs own description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application follows some specific kind of flow to achieve something then you should go for Spring webflow. Otherwise it is not needed in simple applications.

For example if you need to do the user registration process in multiple steps like below.

1. Personal Details.
2. Educational Details.
3. Company Details.
4. Contact Details.

and if you need to get each step data in another step then use of Spring webflow is acceptable.

Hope this helps you.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spring Web Flow is allowing you to represent the UI flow in a web application
in a clear and simple way. This has several advantages:

The UI flow in a web application is clearly visible by looking at the 
corresponding web flow definition (typically in an XML file).

Web Flows can be designed to be self contained.

This allows you to see a part of your application as a module 
and reuse it in multiple situations.


<transition on="enrollCustomer" validate="false" to="redirectToEnrollCustomer" />

<action-state id="redirectToEnrollCustomer">
    <evaluate expression="customerAction.redirectPersonalDetails(flowRequestContext)"/>
    <transition on="success" to="toPersonalDetails"/>
        <transition on="educationSuccess" to="toEducaationDetails"/>
        <transition on="confirmationSuccess" to="toConfirmationDetails"/>
    <transition on="failure" to="enrollCustomer"/>
</action-state>
```